# Maven cannot detect my Node installation

Tags: java, node.js, maven, intellij-idea

I'm running a `Maven` program within `IntelliJ`. When I do the `mvn install` it gives me a bug (that did not exist before).

It says :

```
[INFO] Node not detected. Falling back to rhino

Uglify2 file: /Users/mtaboubi/www/capsana-portal/webapp/unified-portal/src/main/webapp/clients/_assets/js/client_member_facade.js
```

I'm sure that My `Node` is installed ...

What does this mean and how do I resolve this?

Thanks for your help.

---

That's what I got when I run npm install -g :

```
npm install -g
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /Users/mtaboubi
npm ERR! Darwin 14.4.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g"
npm ERR! node v0.12.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.5
npm ERR! code EISDIR
npm ERR! errno -21

npm ERR! EISDIR, read
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/mtaboubi/npm-debug.log
```

Should I do something to resolve these errors ?? thanks –

Answer (score 2):

This is not an error. This is an `[INFO]`. Apparently *Node* is not in your path.

See also [Build failure when Node.js is used over Rhino](https://bugster.forgerock.org/jira/browse/OPENAM-5545).

Comment: Yes, but it really slow down my maven install ... it is like he wanna reproduce things using rhino ...